# C# windows service location

Tags: c#

By using following code[C#], we can know the path where googlechrome is installed. But, this code first starts chrome.exe, then takes its path. My question is without starting chrome.exe, how can I know the path?

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
        string argmnt = @"-g";
        startInfo.Arguments = argmnt;

        String path = null;
        try
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
            path = p.MainModule.FileName;
            p.Kill();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the PATH environment variable and enumerate through all of the directories looking for that exe. This is essentially what the OS does when you call the p.Start method.

Comment: what is that? should I search in windows registry? or somewhere else? could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

First download a tool called "Process Monitor" from Microsoft: [ProcessMonitor available from Microsoft SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) then start up Chrome to find out its location.

**Tip: "Process Monitor" monitors Hard Disk Drive, Registry and Thread/Process information in real time and allows you to save the traces it captures.**

[image]

a. Open Process Monitor, it will start tracing information.

b. Stop the trace by clicking the Magnifying Glass toolbar button (its the On/Off tracing button).

c. Then click the Clear trace button to clear the trace.

d. Start Chrome and once its opened, search for Chrome.exe and it will tell you the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [WHERE](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) command with `chrome.exe` as an argument.  That will tell you the path to the executable that will get loaded by the shell.

You'll just need to read back the output from the command.

This, like your current version, assumes that the executable is in the system PATH.

Here is some code that you can tailor to your needs.  It essentially wraps the WHERE command (which by the way is an executable, so `WHERE WHERE` will reveal its path).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public sealed class WhereWrapper
{
    private static string _exePath = null;

    public static int Main(string[] args) {

        int exitCode;
        string exeToFind = args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : "WHERE";

        Process whereCommand = new Process();

        whereCommand.OutputDataReceived += Where_OutputDataReceived;

        whereCommand.StartInfo.FileName = "WHERE";
        whereCommand.StartInfo.Arguments = exeToFind;
        whereCommand.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        whereCommand.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        whereCommand.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        whereCommand.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        try  {
            whereCommand.Start();
            whereCommand.BeginOutputReadLine();
            whereCommand.BeginErrorReadLine();
            whereCommand.WaitForExit();
            exitCode = whereCommand.ExitCode;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            exitCode = 1;
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        } finally {
            whereCommand.Close();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The path to {0} is {1}", exeToFind, _exePath ?? "{not found}");

        return exitCode;
    }

    private static void Where_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args) {

        if (args.Data != null) {
            _exePath = args.Data;
        }
    }
}
```